# Friction between two bodys ( on top of each other ) - finding acceleration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration, friction

Okay, I have a question.
Lets say the $Fs_{max}$ is 50N.
And I want to find the acceleration of the two bodys.
Untill it was $50N$, they were connected.
but now, the Force is $55N$ ( pushed to the lower body ). that means there aint any friction right?

So if Body A ( Above ) didnt have any force, except the friction from Body B ( Below ), he will be in static, a(acceleration)=$0$. Am I correct?
and Body B ( Below ), will have acceleration ( just has to find it ).

Comment: At the end, I asked a friend and managed to solve it. I was said I should consider the situtation as the two bodys are long - almsot finite, so it doesnt fall off... I guess physics-1 is not that realistic ( atleast now )... Thanks, can close post if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a situation where the applied force acting on a body increases to a point where it exceeds the maximum force of static friction the two surfaces in contact will start to slide relative to each other.  When this happens there will be a switch from static friction to kinetic friction.  For two given surfaces the coefficient of kinetic friction is typically somewhat less than the coefficient of static friction which means once sliding starts the force of friction usually drops but it does not go to zero.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer.
Oh you are right, then I have one last question.
If the max friction ( static ) is 50, and I have force in 55n. does that mean the kinetic friction is 5n? or it doesnt mean it.

Comment: Sorry about the misexplanation. What i mean is: it is problematic. I have to find acceleration of two body's ( I don't know if they are together or in separate), since when the body's are lost contact, the upper body will probably not move.. mean a=0.